# K8s Pod Anti Affinity for Cronjob Pod Even Scheduling

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

In a multi-tenant scenario with `500 namespaces`, each with an identical `Cronjob`, labeled `app=some-job`, and `20 worker nodes`, is it possible to coerce the k8s scheduler to spread the 500 Cronjob Pods evenly across the 20 nodes, such that any node would only have ~25 completed and/or running Pods at a given time?

I've noticed that the 500 Cronjob Pods tend to only be scheduled on roughly 7 out of the 20 nodes, and the `KubeletTooManyPods` alarm fires, even though most of the pods are in the Completed state.

I'm thinking a solution could be to apply a Pod anti-affinity on the label `app=some-job`, with the `topologyKey=kubernetes.io/hostname`, but not sure if this honors `Completed` Pods, and if it would do an even spread once all 20 nodes had at least 1 Pod on them, at which point every node would fail the anti-affinity case, but I hope `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoreDuringExecution` would allow scheduling to continue with an even spread.

Is there a better way to achieve this spread, maybe a custom scheduler?

Edit: Wanted to mention we're using EKS 1.17
Edit 2: Typo

Comment: Looks like `podTopologySpreadConstraints` may have been designed for this scenario. Upgrading to EKS 1.18 would make this available, so I will see if that brings the desired results:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/

Comment: The presence of Complete jobs does not affect the scheduling logic, so I doubt `podTopologySpreadConstraints` will help. You are better off using history limits (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits).

Comment: Depending on what the cronjob does did you consider using daemonsets if you want it to be spread evenly across nodes? These are namespaced objects

Comment: @Oliver, great idea on the history limits! I've got a limit of 1 at the moment, but there's no reason to keep these successful job pod references around, just need if there's a failure. Logging is a minor concern, if there needs to be some post job exploration, but we do ship logs off to ES w/ fluent-bit, so we might have them, depending on the timing of when the container logs disappear from the worker node after pod deletion...

Comment: @MariuszK. Thank you for the input! In this particular scenario, I don't think a deamonset could replace the cronjobs

Comment: @MariuszK. daemonsets do not spread evenly, they allow and ensure only 1 pod on each node, for the daemonset defined.

Comment: @MariuszK. daemonsets do not spread evenly, they allow and ensure only 1 pod on each node, for the daemonset defined. Plus all the cron-related aspects would have to be managed by the daemonset, which will auto-restart pods that exit because a daemonset is designed for pods that are supposed to run indefinitely, whereas cronjobs are designed for pods that exit and must be restarted automatically at scheduled intervals/times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of `Complete` jobs does not affect the scheduling logic, so I doubt `podTopologySpreadConstraints` will help. You are better off using history limits (kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/…)

One of your comments indicates you need the logs: upload the logs of the pod as part of the job, ie at the end of the script run by the cronjob, push to s3 or fluentbit or wherever. Then you are guaranteed that after cronjob completion, the logs are safe. Job logs can disappear for various reasons (they can be cleared, pods can get evicted or deleted, etc), so it is not a good idea to rely on the presence of `Completed` jobs to access them.